# PySpark Aassertion issues

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

We are doing pyspark development(cloudera) and inside the pyspark we are using spark SQL engine to migrated Greenplum to hiveSQL. some of the function getting facing as below error. please suggest.

> An error occurred while calling o72.insertInto. :
> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
> at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.convertToLogicalRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:255)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.convert(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:135)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(HiveStrategies.scala:201)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(HiveStrategies.scala:195)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:71)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:107)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:195)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:179)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
> at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
> at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:68)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:215)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:230)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:77)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:684)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:320)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: please show the code

Comment: select '95'||msisdn as msisdn,
    sum(case when cast(paytype as integer) = 0 
    then (main_acct_rev+ec_rev)*(100.00/105.00) 
    else (main_acct_rev+ec_rev) end) sub_revenue,
    sum(subscription_cnt) subscription_cnt
    from bds.vas_subscription_detail 
    where service_id in ('180','181') and 
    event_date between date_sub('{0}',120) and '{0}'
    group by 1

Comment: select distinct msisdn
    From playground1.vlr_subscriber_location
    where load_dt between date_sub('{0}',7) and '{0}'

Comment: third one i am getting error

Comment: select distinct '95'||subscriber_msisdn msisdn
         from ads.subscriber a join ads.customer b 
         on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
         where b.customer_type in ('4050013','4050002','4050015')
         and subscriber_status not in ('B02','B06')